# Read a file with variable inside a text file

Tags: ruby

Can I read a file containing `#{var_name}`, and when I read and print it, write the value of `var_name`?

I tried using

```
File.open(filename, "w").read
```

to get it as a String, but I didn't find the solution:

```
var_name = "HelloWorld"
f = File.open("file.ex", "r").read
    # puts f.class => String
puts f
    #  #{var_name} is print and no HelloWorld
```

Comment: You can use [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution :

`tamplate.erb` file with your variable inside a `<%= var_name %>`

in `script.rb`

```
require 'erb'
template = File.open("template.erb", "r")
str_template = ERB.new(template.read).result()
template.close

file = File.new("newfile", "w")
file.puts(str_template)
file.close
```

Thanks to Sergio Tulentsev!